# Export TFS Queries

Tags: export, tfs-2015

is it possible to export Work Item Queries from a project? I'm using TFS 2015 and need them stored as .wiq. I know it's possible to save a single query but I need to export a huge amount of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WiQAdmin is probably the easiest http://wiqadmin.codeplex.com/
You'll probably need to do a binding redirect by creating a wiqadmin.exe.config since it is looking for TFS 2012 DLLS, but I have used it with 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TFS REST API ([Get a list of queries](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries))to export the query by using the **expand** option

> http://{tfs_url}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries/My%20Queries%2FBugs?api-version=1.0&$expand=wiql